# Flask token generating

Tags: python, flask, http-authentication

I have a problem while generating token, when i hit '/api/token' its returning method is not allowed. can anybody help me.... Thanks in advance

--------------------app.py--------------------

```
@app.route('/api/token')
@basicAuth.login_required
def get_auth_token():
    token = g.user.generate_auth_token(600)
    return jsonify({ 'token': token.decode('ascii') })
```

-----------models.py--------------

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String())
    last_name = db.Column(db.String())
    email = db.Column(db.String())
    password = db.Column(db.String())
    profile_picture = db.Column(db.String())
    authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def generate_auth_token(self, expiration = 600):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in = expiration)
        return s.dumps({ 'id': user_id })

        def __repr__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.id, self.email)


    @staticmethod
    def verify_auth_token(token):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)
        except SignatureExpired:
            return 'Token Expired'
        except BadSignature:
            return 'Bad Token'
        user = User.query.get(data['id'])
        return user
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set whatever HTTP method you want to use when defining the route. For example, to accept the `GET` and `POST` methods, you would do:

```
@app.route('/api/token', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

The Flask documentation says:

> By default, a route only answers to GET requests, but that can be changed by providing the methods argument to the route() decorator.

From: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#http-methods

Comment: thank you for suggestion... I tried that too, but it is returning Unauthorized Access.

Comment: Did you pass in the basic auth credentials with your request?